# How can I preserve query parameters with Redux and react router?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I'm using React router and i would like to be able to send links or share it but everytime i realload the page, the state is becoming empty

```
http://localhost:3000/project/element=7/userid=9/exercises
```

If i enter this query in the url the state will not be preserved.

Here is my code:

```
<Route
    exact
    path="/project/element=:elementId/userid=:userid/exercises"
    component={Exercises}
    key={`exercises-id`}
/>
```

I tried to:

```
 <Link to="/project/element=:elementId/userid=:userid/exercises" query={this.props.query}
```

But it's not preservering the state of my userId and elementId.

Here is the route:

```
<Route
    exact
    path="/project/element=:elementId/userid=:userid/exercises"
    component={Exercises}
    key={`exercises-id`}
/>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Where do you want to persist it? Your component `Exercises` will receive the parameters and theoretically could persist them.

Comment: Yes in the exercises component, but i'm not sure how to do it

Comment: @Yannis just FYI /element=7/userid=9/ is a really weird way to mix query params syntax and path params syntax. The convention is to do either /elements/7/user/9 oder have both as query params: /project/exercises?element=<elementId>&user=<userId>.

Answer (score 1):

`path="/project/element=:elementId/userid=:userid/exercises"`

Should be

`path="/project/element/:elementId/userid/:userid/exercises"`
inside

Comment: Your path correction is wierd, did you forgot the first "query parameter" (`element=:elementId`) ?

Comment: oh...My bad @Darkilen